# regex to replace alphanumeric strings only

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on a tool that tags alphanumeric words with the option selected from right click context menu. I am having issues when group of words are selected with some special characters in it.

I am using this RegEx that I found on this site itself: `/(\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g`

To reproduce the problem, select `123b @#$@#$` or `@#$@#$ a` from the text and right click and select any option. The expected result is `[TAG] 123b @#$@#$` or `@#$@#$ [TAG] a` respectively.

Also, it doesn't work if I try to tag the following complete string: 
`rahul@gmail.com 123a % / ! @$# % % %^* && ^ Lorem ipsum`
The expected result for this is: 
`[TAG] rahul@gmail.com  [TAG] 123a % / ! @$# % % %^* && ^  [TAG] Lorem  [TAG] ipsum`.

Ideally, it should tag strings like `123abc`, `abc123`, `12ab3` - with any number of digits and letters. If a string like email address is selected, that should be tagged as well.

How do I fix this?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/vzynhtak/14/)

HTML:

```
<p contenteditable="true">rahul@gmail.com 123a % / ! @$# % % %^* && ^ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer augue tortor, dictum a turpis non, dapibus vehicula neque. 123b @#$@#$ a quam vel cursus. Duis at mattis quam, ornare consequat enim. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer augue tortor, dictum a turpis non, dapibus vehicula neque. Aliquam dictum a quam vel cursus. Duis at mattis quam, ornare consequat enim. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
```

JS:

```
function replaceText(selectedText, selectedTag){
    if(selectedText == "")
        return false;
    if(selectedText.match(/^[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]/))
        replacedText = selectedText.replace(/(\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g, " " + selectedTag + " " + "$1");
    else
        replacedText = selectedTag + " " + selectedText.replace(/(\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g, " " + selectedTag + " " + "$1");
    originalText = $('p').html();
    newText = originalText.replace( new RegExp(selectedText,"g") , replacedText);
    $('p').html(newText);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple, they said.

I broke down every word in folowing categories:

1. alphanumeric
2. alphanumeric followed by . or , (as in a sentence)
3. email

Then I added tag to it and replaced it in the main text. Thats it!

```
function replaceText(selectedText, selectedTag){
    if(selectedText == "") {
        return false;
    }
    else{
        var selectedTextArray = selectedText.split(" ");

        originalText = $('p').html();

        selectedTextArray.forEach(function(item){
            if(item.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/) // alphanumeric
               || item.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9.,]+$/) // alphanumeric followed by . or ,
               || item.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+))/) // email               
                ){
                    originalText = originalText.replace(new RegExp("\\b" + item + "\\b","g") , selectedTag + " " + item);

                }                 
        });
        newText = originalText;
    }

    $('p').html(newText);
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/vzynhtak/43/)

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the updated code.**

**Note:** I have updated the else part to first remove all special characters and then replace all the occurrence of a string with **[tag] + string**.

HTML:

```
<p contenteditable="true">rahul@gmail.com 123a % / ! @$# % % %^* && ^ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer augue tortor, dictum a turpis non, dapibus vehicula neque. 123b @#$@#$ a quam vel cursus. Duis at mattis quam, ornare consequat enim. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer augue tortor, dictum a turpis non, dapibus vehicula neque. Aliquam dictum a quam vel cursus. Duis at mattis quam, ornare consequat enim. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
var selectedTag, selectedText, originalText, newText, replacedText, selectedTextArray;

function getSelectedText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}

function replaceText(selectedText, selectedTag){
    if(selectedText == "") {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        selectedText = selectedText.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g,'');
        selectedText = selectedText.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');
        selectedTextArray = selectedText.split(" ");
    }
    if(selectedTextArray.length > 0) {
        var selectedTextPart = '';
        originalText = $('p').html();
        newText = originalText;
        for(var i=0; i<selectedTextArray.length; i++) {
            selectedTextPart = selectedTextArray[i];
            selectedTextPart = new RegExp("\\b"+selectedTextPart+"\\b", "g");
            replacedText = selectedTag+' '+'$&';
            newText = newText.replace( selectedTextPart , replacedText);
        }
        $('p').html(newText);
    }
}

$.contextMenu({
    selector: 'p', 
    callback: function(key, options) {
        selectedTag = key;
        selectedText = $.trim(getSelectedText());
        replaceText(selectedText, selectedTag);
    },
    items: {
        "[ORG]": {name: "[ORG]"},
        "[PER]": {name: "[PER]"},
        "[LOC]": {name: "[LOC]"}
    }
});
```

Comment: Works very well for the strings mentioned in the question. But, what if I select `123a % / ! @$# % % %^* && ^ Lorem ` ?

Comment: @RahulDesai Write down the result also you expect if the string you select is this **123a % / ! @$# % % %^* && ^ Lorem**.
What result do you expect if you select this string ??

Comment: Updated in the question.

Comment: @RahulDesai I have updated the code in the answer provided.
And also updated the JSFiddle link. - [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Varun_Chakervarti/vzynhtak/37/)

Comment: I tested [your code in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/vzynhtak/38/), it didnt work for the email ID at the beginning. Rest all is working great!

Comment: @RahulDesai Is because the email ID contains the special character @ in it. And your expectations is to skip @ if not in email ID.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65292/discussion-between-varun-chakervarti-and-rahul-desai).